# By using digits in file name like 1.0.0.1, the file name will be truncated and displays like this 1.0

Tags: macos, finder

By using digits in file names like 1.0.0.1 (with an arbitrary file type like .pdf, .txt or .jpg), the file name will be truncated and displays like this 1.0 (the .0.1 part will be truncated)

I already set grid view in the view options, but it doesn't help.

I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Please suggest how I may see the full name?

Answer (score 1):

Command-I will bring up the Info panel; can you see the entire name there? If not, then edit to see I'd you can change it. 
I'm having an issue where a .app file with a 2 decimal number starts showing the extension (so instead of iMovie 2.1.3, it shows iMovie 2.1.3.app). So it's possible OS X just doesn't like the decimals